# setInterval, this, again

Tags: javascript, scope, setinterval

I have a problem in regard to `setInterval` that I can't figure out.

There is the problem with the scope when calling `setInterval` or timeout from within an object, but still I can't wrap my head around it.

I tried to put my stuff inside an anonymous function, it won't work.

This is basicly my problem, simplified to the bare bones:

```
function Scenario(){
    var ships = [];
    this.ini = function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < ships.length; i++){
            timeoutID1 = setTimeout(ships[i].ding, 1000);
            timeoutID2 = setTimeout(ships[i].bing, 1000);
        }
    }
    this.setShips = function(){
        var ship = new Ship("ship");
        ships.push(ship);    
    }        

    function Ship(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.ding = function(){
            intervalID1 = setInterval(function(){
                console.log("ding");
            }, 500)      
        }
        this.bing = function(){
            var _this = this;
            intervalID2 = setInterval(function(){
                console.log(_this.name);
            }, 500)      
        }
    }
    this.setShips();
}

var scenario = new Scenario();
scenario.ini();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ancientsion/xkwsn7xd/

Basicly, `console.log("ding")` works, `console.log(_this.name)` doesn't.

Why?

Comment: You're combining `setTimeout` with `setInterval` for the ultimate punishment? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time `setTimeout()` gets around to call your method, it only sees the function and not the invocation context (i.e. the object to bind it to); much like this:

```
var bing = ships[i].bing;

bing(); // inside bing(), this == window
```

Basically, you need to provide `setTimeout()` with a prewired method invocation:

```
var bound_bing = ships[i].bing.bind(ships[i]);
timeoutID2 = setTimeout(bound_bing, 1000);
```

The "magic" happens with [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) as it returns a new function that will have `this` set up properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem simplified to bare bones:

```
var ship = {
    name: 'Sheep',
    ding: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

setTimeout(ship.ding, 1000); // doesn't work correctly
```

It may help to see another example to understand why the above doesn't work:

```
var ding = ship.ding;
ding(); // doesn't work either
```

In JavaScript `this` depends on how you call your function. `ship.ding()` will set `this` to the `sheep` object. Bare `ding()` call will set `this` to the `window` object.

You can bind the function to the object you want by using `.bind()` method. ([Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind))

```
var ding = ship.ding.bind(ship);
ding(); // works
```

`ding` is now permanently bound to the `sheep` object. You can use exactly the same approach with `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(ship.ding.bind(ship), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the value `_this` in `Ship` function:

```
function Ship(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.ding = function(){
        intervalID1 = setInterval(function(){
            console.log("ding");
        }, 500)      
    }
    var _this = this;
    this.bing = function(){
        intervalID2 = setInterval(function(){
            console.log(_this.name);
        }, 500)      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoist _this out of the bing function.

you should have

```
_this = this,
this.bing = function() {
            intervalID2 = setInterval(function(){
                console.log(_this.name);
            }, 500)   
}
```

Javascript is imperative so you need to follow the execution path carefully.  In function Ship, this points to a Ship object, in function bing, this points to the global scope (window).  You need to save a reference to this so that you can refer back to it in these types of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You put `ships[i].bing` in setTimeout turns out that the caller of bing is not ships[i] but global, so `_this` is pointing to global actually.